# object creation in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, class, object

We create Objects in flex by declaring type Object.
for example

```
var objSampleObject:Object = new Object();
```

and we create properties directly with dot operator without creating any class

```
objSampleObject.name="xxx";
objSampleObject.id=123;
```

My question is in above process is there any class is created internally by flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a class is created internally, not by Flex, but by the Flash runtime. Is there any reason why you need to know that?

Comment: Other langugaes (ex: .NET) will not support creating objects wthout class. so..  :)

Comment: The class `Object` is actually declared in the Flash runtime as `public dynamic class Object`. Since it's dynamic, it means you can add properties to it at runtime.

Comment: .Net isn't dynamic.  Flash is.  However, creating dynamic objects are not recommended because of the problems it can cause with dynamic properties and general class typing.

Comment: @ J_A_X thats why .NET object  and flex object are different.. if we send flex object to .net we will not access or modify any of the properties of flex object.

Answer (score 1):

In Flex we use SDK's to build the app's, Flex SDK includes the Flex framework also known as the "Flex class library" in this library all the classes defined, and using the SDK's in flex we can access all the property of that particular class using Dot(.) operator.

Hope [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  **Array and Object Creation**

 private function addtext(event):void {

                    var str:String=ta.text;

                    var mydata:Array=str.split("\r");
                    for each(var data:String in mydata){ 
                        var obj:Object = new Object();
                        obj.name=data
                        mylist.addItem(obj);
                        clearInputs();

                    }


                }
            <mx:LinkButton label="{data.name}"  />
```